# CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess is left running with high CPU if app crashes

Tags: cefsharp

I'm making use of the excellent [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/) project (version 67) to host a browser in our WPF application.

Making use of CefSharp causes child `CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess` processes to be started, which is by design.

These processes are stopped if I cleanly exit my application and call `Cef.Shutdown()` as recommended in the [documentation](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Cef_Shutdown.htm):

```cs
// Hook up handler earlier in application
Application.Current.Exit += OnApplicationExit;

...

private void OnApplicationExit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess() == false)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => OnApplicationExit(sender, e));
        return;
    }

    // Stops CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess processes
    Cef.Shutdown();
}
```

I've noticed that if the application is killed, the `CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess` responsible for rendering is left running and starts using a *lot* of CPU and does so indefinitely.

I can add some code to handle this, checking for any orphaned `CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess` process, and kill them. I'm wondering if there's a better option though?

It would be great if the process itself could perform a period check itself and kill itself, perhaps as a setting.

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_CefSharpSettings_SubprocessExitIfParentProcessClosed.htm

Comment: Once it's had more testing will be enabled by default

Comment: Thanks for the fast response @amaitland - that worked brilliantly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered by @amaitland, the following setting should be set to monitor the parent process:

`CefSharpSettings.SubprocessExitIfParentProcessClosed = true;`